# Unable to access boto3 on EMR 5.28.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I created an EMR cluster using the AWS UI but did not bootstrap to install boto3. Now, I am getting to execute pyspark scripts which use boto3. So, I SSH to the master node and am attempting to install boto3. Below is screen shot I gathered to show as if I am installing it again (so the messages are saying that it is already installed), but you get the point. Then I run Python3 interactively to test boto3 and it can't find it. What am I doing wrong? Also, will I need to install boto3 on the slave nodes as well?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You install boto3 for Python2, so you don't see it from Python3.
Try to install boto3 with pip3:

```
pip3 install boto3 --user
```